# How to select correct values from multiple level object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
const options = {
option1: 'big',
option2: undefined,
option3: [],
option4: ['heavy'],
optionList: {
  option5: undefined,
  option6: true,
  option7: ['blue', 'pink', 'green']
  }
}
```

I want to build URL based on it. Option needs to be skipped if it's either `undefined`, or has empty array. If option is object, options inside of it should go through same check. Based on object I have I want to get URL:

```
?option1=big&option4=heavy&option6=true&option7=blue&option7=pink&option7=green
```

was thinking of possibly using `new URLSearchParams`, but not sure how to convert above object efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun problem to try and solve. I think I got a working solution for you.

```
function nestedObj(obj) {
  let optionStrings = [];

  function recursiveHelper(obj) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(
      obj
    )) {
      if (
        typeof value === 'object' &&
        !value.length
      ) {
        recursiveHelper(value);
      } else if (
        value !== undefined &&
        typeof value === 'object' &&
        value.length > 0
      ) {
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          optionStrings.push(
            `${key}=${value[i]}`
          );
        }
      } else if (value !== undefined) {
        optionStrings.push(`${key}=${value}`);
      }
    }
  }

  recursiveHelper(obj);
  return optionStrings;
}

const options = {
  option1: 'big',
  option2: undefined,
  option3: [],
  option4: ['heavy'],
  optionList: {
    option5: undefined,
    option6: true,
    option7: ['blue', 'pink', 'green'],
  },
};

let queryStringArray = nestedObj(options);

let queryString = `?${queryStringArray.join(
  '&'
)}`;

console.log(queryString);
```

Your constraints made the if/else if logic interesting. The if statement in the `recursiveHelper` function checks whether the type of value is an object, if so, then checks whether it is an array by seeing if the value property is defined since arrays have that property. The `else if` statement checks that the current value is not undefined and checks if the value is not an empty array by once again confirming it is an object type with a length property defined and with a length greater than 0 so that we can loop through the array if there are multiple options as was the case for `option7` property. The last `else if` statement is any other value such as a string, boolean value, or number and creates the necessary string to push on the `optionStrings` array. The `optionStrings` array is then returned after the recursive function finishes executing so that we can join the different optionStrings using the `join` method available on arrays to form the final query string. I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issue for this conversion;

1. filtering nested object (which depend on value (not undefined))
2. crumble to array item (for desired url query)

```
function recursiveObjectFilter(obj = {}){
    let result = {};

    for(let key in obj){
        let currentItem = obj[key];

        //INFO: checks value exist?
        if(currentItem !== undefined){
            //WARNING: arrays return 'object' so we have to check is this value array or object
            if(typeof currentItem == 'object'){
                if(Array.isArray(currentItem)){
                    if(currentItem.length){
                        result[key] = currentItem;
                    }
                }else{
                    //INFO: call 'recursiveObjectFilter' for child objects and merge result
                    let subResult = recursiveObjectFilter(currentItem);
                    result = {
                        ...result,
                        ...subResult
                    }
                }
            }else{
                result[key] = currentItem;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function generateKeyValueArray(obj = {}){
    let result = [];

    for(let key in obj){
        let currentValue = obj[key];

        if(Array.isArray(currentValue)){
            for(let i in currentValue){
                let currentArrayValue = currentValue[i];

                let currentPair = [key, currentArrayValue];
                result.push(currentPair);
            }
        }else{
            let currentPair = [key, currentValue];
            result.push(currentPair);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function generateUrlSearchParams(valueObj = {}){
    let filteredValueObj = recursiveObjectFilter(valueObj);
    //INFO: URLSearchParams accepts Objects but array values must be pass as seperated key/value pairs for desired result (`option7=blue&option7=pink&option7=green`), so we use translation.  
    let urlSearchParamsDataSource = generateKeyValueArray(filteredValueObj);
    
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(urlSearchParamsDataSource);

    return urlSearchParams;
}

const options = {
    option1: 'big',
    option2: undefined,
    option3: [],
    option4: ['heavy'],
    optionList: {
        option5: undefined,
        option6: true,
        option7: ['blue', 'pink', 'green']
    }
}

let myUrlSearchParams = generateUrlSearchParams(options);
console.log(myUrlSearchParams.toString());
//Prints 'option1=big&option4=heavy&option6=true&option7=blue&option7=pink&option7=green'
```

`recursiveObjectFilter` function filter values (but if there is an item with the same key with parent items, its overide value)

`generateKeyValueArray` function generate key/value pair array which in this case returns `[["option1","big"],["option4","heavy"],["option6",true],["option7","blue"],["option7","pink"],["option7","green"]]`

abstracting functions will be useful for clean code and reusability.